# Auto refresh content but not if focus on the one of the inputs in this content

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have view:

```
...   
<div id="actualverses">
@Html.Action("Render3ActualVerses")
</div>
...
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
    $('#actualverses').load('/Verse/Render3ActualVerses'); }, 3000);
    });

</script>
```

all works fine but in the div with id "actualverses" is inputs and I want to refresh this view but not if the focus one one of the inputs. Something like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(function () {
    if(??? !focus on the $('#txtString')){
        setInterval(function () {
        $('#actualverses').load('/Verse/Render3ActualVerses'); }, 3000);
        }
    });

</script>
```

how to write "if not focus on the element with id/name = "txtString"" in JavaScript?

I need this for this site: http://boutsrimes.somee.com/
I want to refresh content of the div with id 'actualverses' but not if user type something in inputs in this div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.is(":focus")`

```
$(function () {
     setInterval(function () {
        if ($("#txtString").is(":focus")) 
        $('#actualverses').load('/Verse/Render3ActualVerses');           
     }, 3000);

});
```